# Displaying stored Variables with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables

i am writing a simple quiz where the answers are stored in 5 variables. after the 5th question i would like the results to display.

Before the jquery implementation to hide the next question i used
documents.write.Rus (rus being the variable). this worked but i can't figure out how to implement it within my jquery code. Can someone take a look?

here is my javascript & html code :

```js
function check() {
  var Rus = 0;
  var Zin = 0;
  var Duu = 0;
  var Ver = 0;
  var Zor = 0;

  var q1 = document.quiz.q1.value;
  if (q1 == "Rus") {
    Rus++
  }
  if (q1 == "Zin") {
    Zin++
  }
  if (q1 == "Duu") {
    Duu++
  }
  if (q1 == "Ver") {
    Ver++
  }
  if (q1 == "Zor") {
    Zor++
  }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide all questions
  $('.questionForm').hide();
  $('#results').hide();
  //show first question 
  $('#q1').show();

  $('#q1 #button').click(function() {
    $('.questionForm').hide();
    $('.results').hide();
    $('#q2').show();
    return false;
  });

  $('#q2 #button').click(function() {
    $('.questionForm').hide();
    $('#results').hide();
    $('#q3').show();
    return false;
  });

  $('#q3 #button').click(function() {
    $('.questionForm').hide();
    $('#results').hide();
    $('#q4').show();
    return false;
  });

  $('#q4 #button').click(function() {
    $('.questionForm').hide();
    $('#results').hide();
    $('#q5').show();
    return false;
  });

  $('#q5 #button').click(function() {
    $('.questionForm').hide();
    // show results 
    $('#results').show();
    $Rus.show();

    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="STYLE.CSS">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="questionForm" name="quiz" id="q1" data-question="1">
    <div>
      <p>Question 1</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Rus">A. Rustgeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Zin">B. Zingeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Duu">C. Duurzaamheid</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Ver">D. Verzuiling</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Zor">D. Zorgzaamheid</p>
    </div>
    <input class="favorite styled" id="button" type="button" value="Volgende" onclick="check()">
  </form>

  <form class="questionForm" name="quiz" id="q2" data-question="2">
    <div>
      <p>Question 2</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Rus">A. Rustgeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Zin">B. Zingeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Duu">C. Duurzaamheid</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Ver">D. Verzuiling</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Zor">D. Zorgzaamheid</p>
    </div>
    <input class="favorite styled" id="button" type="button" value="Volgende" onclick="check()">
  </form>

  <form class="questionForm" name="quiz" id="q3" data-question="3">
    <div>
      <p>Question 3</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Rus">A. Rustgeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Zin">B. Zingeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Duu">C. Duurzaamheid</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Ver">D. Verzuiling</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Zor">D. Zorgzaamheid</p>
    </div>
    <input class="favorite styled" id="button" type="button" value="Volgende" onclick="check()">
  </form>

  <form class="questionForm" name="quiz" id="q4" data-question="4">
    <div>
      <p>Question 4</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Rus">A. Rustgeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Zin">B. Zingeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Duu">C. Duurzaamheid</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Ver">D. Verzuiling</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Zor">D. Zorgzaamheid</p>
    </div>
    <input class="favorite styled" id="button" type="button" value="Volgende" onclick="check()">
  </form>

  <form class="questionForm" name="quiz" id="q5" data-question="5">
    <div>
      <p>Question 5</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Rus">A. Rustgeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Zin">B. Zingeving</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Duu">C. Duurzaamheid</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Ver">D. Verzuiling</p>
      <p><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Zor">D. Zorgzaamheid</p>
    </div>
    <input class="favorite styled" id="button" type="button" value="Volgende" onclick="check()">
  </form>

  <div name="results" id="results">
    <p1>Results</p1>

  </div>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="quiz.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure how your html loots, but i believe you have a problem, you seem to have duplicated id's `#button`,`#results`

Comment: I have attached my HTML code, so far clicking between questions works fine. but storing the answers in the variables and displaying them when i reach the result screen is the problem.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) - eg `$("#results").append((Rus + Zin + Duu + Ver + Zor) + " correct");`.  But you need quite a bit more than just that to complete, it's just the output part.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for that. using the above code still makes it show up blank after question 5, what direction do i need to look/ what am i missing?

Comment: Well, this isn't https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but here's some pointers:  1) stick with js/jquery events, remove all `onclick=` as having them in two places is confusing.   2) use classes not Ids (as noted above they should be unique)

Comment: 3) use data-driven not id-driven, eg `$(".question .answer-button")` instead of multiple event handlers, then get the question number from the HTML directly - you do already have this as `data-question="2"` so `$(".answer-button").click(function() { $(this).closest(".questionForm").data("question")...` would give you the question number and allow you to move to the next one 4) you don't need separate variables for your score, nor keep track "as you go" - instead  calculate directly from the html each time